# Using an adjective as a noun in the plural form

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, nominal-adjectives

Which question is the more correct or the more colloquial?
1- "Why are they (those school subjects that you just mentioned) your FAVOURITE?"
2- or "Why are they (those school subjects that you just mentioned) your FAVOURITES?"

Comment: I would use "Why are those your FAVOURITE subjects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct: 'Why are they your **favourite**s?'

Incorrect: Why are they your *favourite*? [A plural noun should be used with 'they'. favourite- singular noun, favourites- plural noun ]

Favourite (**noun**)- Why are those your **favourites**? (those school subjects that you just mentioned)

Favourite (**adjective**)- Why are those your **favourite** subjects?

-'Which are your favourite subjects?' -'My favourite subjects are English and History.

-'Which (subjects) are your favourites?' -'English and History are my favourites.'

Answer (score 2):

'Favourite' is sometimes used alone as a noun, but is also used as an adjective alongside another noun:

- Which subject is your *favourite*?
- Which is your *favourite subject*?

When used alone, it is singular or plural depending on whether you are referring to a single thing, or many things:

- Which subject **is** your *favourite*?
- Which subects **are** your *favourites*?

But as part of a compound noun, it would be the other noun that is pluralised, if appropriate:

- Which is your favourite subject?
- Which are your favourite subjects?

In your example, it sounds like 3 subjects have been chosen as 'favourite' (most favoured). In this kind of example, it is also normal to use the singular *favourite* to ask about them *collectively*, so you could use either 'favourites' to refer to the subjects as individual items, or 'favourite' to refer to them collectively as the favourite subjects.

Comment: I would not say that "favourite subject" is a compound noun... My question is about the reason why the just-mentioned subjects should be the person's favourites. I don't get it when you say that I must be speaking of 3 subjects, why not two?